# Write a database function that should display {1} if object exists {0} if object does not exist in the database

Tags: oracle, plsql

Help me finish this function, please. If you could proof read and correct my mistake I could really appreciate it.

a.  The function takes two INPUT parameters {object_name, object_type} and return an INT.

Object Names and Object Types are related as follows.

b.  {object_name} can be any database object like TABLES, SEQUENCES, SYNONYMS, VIEWS.

c.  {object_type} can be {T, SEQ, SYN, V}. Each object type corresponds to its object names.
T=>TABLES, SYN=>SYNONYMS, SEQ=>SEQUENCES, V=>VIEWS.

For example if I pass the object_name as ‘EMPLOYEES’, object_type as ‘T’ then it should check if this object in the database and then return either {1} or {0}.

```
create or replace function OBJECT_CHECK (object_name varchar, 
                        object_type varchar,
                       )
return int 

AS
BEGIN 

DECLARE
v_Number NUMBER;
V_NUMBER1 NUMBER;
v_str VARCHAR2(100);
OBJECTS_NAME VARCHAR2(100):='&object';
v_tab VARCHAR2(100);

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(* ) --for tables checking
INTO v_Number
FROM User_Tables
WHERE Table_Name = UPPER(OBJECTS_NAME);
v_str :='TABLE_NAME';
IF V_NUMBER =0 THEN -- for synonyms checking
SELECT COUNT(* )
INTO v_Number
FROM user_synonyms
WHERE synonym_Name = UPPER(OBJECTS_NAME);
v_str :='SYNONYM';
END IF;

--dbms_output.put_line(v_number);
v_str:='INDEX';
END IF;
IF V_NUMBER = 0 THEN -- for COLUMN checking
BEGIN
FOR i IN
(SELECT table_name FROM all_tab_cols WHERE column_name =UPPER(OBJECTS_NAME)
)
LOOP
dbms_output.put_line(UPPER(OBJECTS_NAME)|| ' Coulmn available in ' ||        
i.table_name || ' table ');
END LOOP;
v_str:='colum';
END;
END IF;
IF V_NUMBER = 0 THEN 
SELECT count(*)
into v_number FROM all_tab_cols WHERE column_name =UPPER(OBJECTS_NAME);
end if;
IF v_Number >= 1 AND v_str='TABLE_NAME' THEN
dbms_Output.Put_Line(UPPER(OBJECTS_NAME) ||'-----> TABLE IS AVAILABLE IN THE       
SCHEMA ' );
ELSE
dbms_Output.Put_Line(UPPER(OBJECTS_NAME) ||'-----> NO SUCH TABLE AVAILABLE IN    
THE SCHEMA ' );
END IF;
IF v_Number >= 1 AND v_str='SYNONYM' THEN
dbms_Output.Put_Line(UPPER(OBJECTS_NAME) ||'-----> SYNONYM IS AVAILABLE IN THE   
SCHEMA ' );
ELSE
dbms_Output.Put_Line(UPPER(OBJECTS_NAME) ||'-----> NO SUCH SYNONYM AVAILABLE   
IN THE SCHEMA ' );
END IF;
IF v_Number >= 1 AND v_str='INDEX' THEN
dbms_Output.Put_Line(UPPER(OBJECTS_NAME) ||'-----> INDEX IS AVAILABLE IN THE     
SCHEMA ' );
ELSE
dbms_Output.Put_Line(UPPER(OBJECTS_NAME) ||'-----> NO SUCH INDEX AVAILABLE IN   
THE SCHEMA ' );
END IF;
IF v_Number = 0 or V_STR <>'colum' THEN
dbms_Output.Put_Line(UPPER(OBJECTS_NAME) ||'-----> NO SUCH COLUMN AVAILABLE IN   
THE SCHEMA ' );
END IF;


END;

END;
```

Comment: What is the **specific** problem you are having?

Comment: Any reason you are not using the sys.all_objects view? This view contains tables, indexes, synonyms ect all in one place rather than having to look in multiple places...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the problem you're referring to, but you've got some syntax errors. You should have received error messages pointing you to these. However...

You have a comma here...remove it

```
create or replace function OBJECT_CHECK (object_name varchar, 
                        object_type varchar, <--HERE
                       )
return int
```

And you have an extra `end` here as well

```
END;

END;
```